# HTTP POST Though C#

Tags: c#, .net, http-post

I want to code an auto bot for an online game (tribalwars.net). I'm learning C# in school, but haven't covered networking yet.

Is it possible to make HTTP POSTs though C#? Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 10):

Trivial with [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

```
using(WebClient client = new WebClient()) {
    string responseString = client.UploadString(address, requestString);
}
```

There is also:

- UploadData - binary (`byte[]`)
- UploadFile - from a file
- UploadValues - name/value pairs (like a form)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [System.Net.HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx):

Request

```
HttpWebRequest request= (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.Method = "POST";
request.KeepAlive = true;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    requestStream.Write(BytePost,0,BytePost.Length);
    requestStream.Close();
}
```

Response

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    responseString = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: You should encase the using in a try-catch block so that you can capture data from 400 or 500 errors.

Answer (score 0):

[Here's](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=32254) a good example.  You want to use the WebRequest class in C#, which will make this easy.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is old question, but posting this for someone looking for quick example on how to send Http Post request with json body in latest .NET (Core 5), using `HttpClient` (part of `System.Net.Http` namespace). Example:

```
//Initialise httpClient, preferably static in some common or util class.
public class Common
{
    public static HttpClient HttpClient => new HttpClient
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://example.com")
    };
}

public class User
{
    //Function, where you want to post data to api
    public void CreateUser(User user)
    {
        try
        {
            //Set path to api
            var apiUrl = "/api/users";

            //Initialize Json body to be sent with request. Import namespaces Newtonsoft.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.Linq, to use JsonConvert and JObject.
            var jObj = JObject.Parse(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
            var jsonBody = new StringContent(jObj.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            //Initialize the http request message, and attach json body to it
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, apiUrl)
            {
                Content = jsonBody
            };

            // If you want to send headers like auth token, keys, etc then attach it to request header
            var apiKey = "qwerty";
            request.Headers.Add("api-key", apiKey);

            //Get the response
            using var response = Common.HttpClient.Send(request);

            //EnsureSuccessStatusCode() checks if response is successful, else will throw an exception
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            //handle exception
        }
        
    }
}
```

Why is HttpClient static or recommended to be instantiated once per application:

> HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout
> the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for
> every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy
> loads. This will result in SocketException errors.

HttpClient class has async methods too. More info on `HttpClient` class: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0